# tf2::fromMsg cause "Undefined reference"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to convert `geometry_msgs::Point` into `tf2::Vector3` to do some computation. There has an API [void tf2::fromMsg (const geometry_msgs::Point &in, tf2::Vector3 &out)](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/tf2_geometry_msgs/html/c++/namespacetf2.html) to do so, but it causes `undefined reference`, below is the error when I build my package.

`undefined reference to 'void tf2::fromMsg<geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> >, tf2::Vector3>(geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> > const&, tf2::Vector3&)'`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Below is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(clean_viz)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    geometry_msgs
    roscpp
    std_msgs
    tf2_geometry_msgs
    tf2_ros
    visualization_msgs
)


catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    geometry_msgs
    roscpp
    std_msgs
    tf2_geometry_msgs
    tf2_ros
    visualization_msgs
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(clean_viz src/clean_viz.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
  clean_viz
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
```

Anybody know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267657/tf2::frommsg-cause-%22undefined-reference%22/) by [Steven Wei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31364/steven-wei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-07-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-07-30**:
Could you show your CMakelists.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to include the header that defines that method in your source.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2